# Solr mixed up "television" and "televisions"

Tags: solr, stemming

I have bunch of documents with bunch of random words in each. Solr output is messed up for the words *television* and *televisions* ([Results for *televisions*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnSsi.jpg))...i.e. when I search for *televisions* it gives me results for *television* and *televisions* altogether. It's only about the word **television** and its plural; Solr works fine for other words and their plurals. For example, it works fine for *car* and *cars* ([Results for *car*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmJp1.jpg)). What could be the issue?

Comment: What is the definition of the field?

Comment: I search against all fields and they're basically default fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solr comes with support for synonyms out of the box and for 99.99% of the cases you must define what words are synonyms. The two exceptions are the words "television" and "gigabyte" since those come already defined in the default `synonyms.txt` file that Solr uses.

You can see this in the `conf` folder of your core:

```
$ cat /path/to/solr/server/solr/your-core/conf/synonyms.txt

# Some synonym groups specific to this example
GB,gib,gigabyte,gigabytes
MB,mib,megabyte,megabytes
Television, Televisions, TV, TVs
```

Notice how it defines that TV, Television, Televisions, and TVs are synonyms.

You can read more about this here too: 
https://github.com/hectorcorrea/solr-for-newbies/blob/master/tutorial.md#synonyms